# Doubt while completing the square in the generating functional of free scalar theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, greens-functions

Consider the free massive real scalar field in 4 Euclidean dimensions. The generating functional for Correlation functions is
$$
Z[J]=\int[d\phi]\exp\bigg(\int d^4x\,[-\frac{1}{2}\phi(-\partial^2+m^2)\phi+J\phi]\bigg)
$$
This functional integral can be done exactly, and I am trying to figure out a step in the process. The key is the functional version of completing the square. We basically make the following variable change
$$
\phi=\varphi+L^{-1}J
$$
where $L=(-\partial^2+m^2)$ and $L^{-1}$ is its inverse. This (assuming that the integration measure remains invariant with such a variable change) leads us to
$$
Z[J]=\int[d\varphi]\exp\bigg(\int d^4x\,[-\frac{1}{2}(\varphi+L^{-1}J)L(\varphi+L^{-1}J)+J(\varphi+L^{-1}J)]\bigg)
$$
$$
=\int[d\varphi]\exp\bigg(\int d^4x\,[-\frac{1}{2}\varphi L\varphi-\frac{1}{2}(L^{-1}J)L\varphi-\frac{1}{2}\varphi L(L^{-1}J)-\frac{1}{2}(L^{-1}J)L(L^{-1}J)+J\varphi+JL^{-1}J]\bigg)
$$
$$
=\int[d\varphi]\exp\bigg(\int d^4x\,[-\frac{1}{2}\varphi L\varphi-\frac{1}{2}(L^{-1}J)L\varphi-\frac{1}{2}\varphi J-\frac{1}{2}(L^{-1}J)J+J\varphi+JL^{-1}J]\bigg)
$$
$$
=\int[d\varphi]\exp\bigg(\int d^4x\,[-\frac{1}{2}\varphi L\varphi-\frac{1}{2}(L^{-1}J)L\varphi+\frac{1}{2}\varphi J+\frac{1}{2}JL^{-1}J]\bigg)
$$
I know that the result is supposed to be
$$
Z[J]=\int[d\varphi]\exp\bigg(\int d^4x\,[-\frac{1}{2}\varphi L\varphi+\frac{1}{2}JL^{-1}J]\bigg)
$$
So that 
$$
(L^{-1}J)L\varphi=J\varphi
$$
but I do not know how to prove it. So how is the last identity proved?

Comment: Hint : For the green's function $[-\partial_{1}^{2}+m_{}^{2}]G(1,2)=\delta(1,2)$ apply Green's identity with the condition that $G$ and $\vec{\partial}G$ both vanish on the space-time boundary which is ok since, it is generally assumed that sources $J$ vanish on space time boundary. This proves symmetry $G(1,2) = G(2,1)$. In your notation, this translates to $L_{}^{-1} J=J L_{}^{-1}$.

Comment: Also it is assumed that fields $\phi$ vanish on space time boundary.